# Arbitrary Dimensional Array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I'm trying to create an n-dimensional array structure for use in a maze generating program.

I've simplified my problem (for the purposes of trying to get the theory figured out before making it templatized and adding all the necessary helper functions)

So my problem currently boils down to wanting to make an ArbitraryArray class that takes in an argument to its constructor specifying the number of dimensions. Each dimension will have length = 5. (for now)

This is what I have so far:

```
class ArbitraryArray{
public:
    int array[5];
    ArbitraryArray*subArray;

    ArbitraryArray(){}

    ArbitraryArray(int depth){
        if (depth == 2) subArray = new ArbitraryArray[5];
        else if (depth > 2) for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) subArray = new ArbitraryArray(depth - 1);
    }
};
```

And I'd create a 2 dimensional object like so:

```
ArbitraryArray testArray(2);
```

Or a 3 dimensional object like so:

```
ArbitraryArray testArray(3);
```

Problem is, when I tested it for depth = 3 and then tried to set an integer value, via:

```
testArray.subArray[3].subArray[4].array[4] = 7;
```

I received a runtime error, leading me to believe that I'm doing something wrong in how I allocate these objects dynamically.

Also, I included an empty default constructor since that gets called by lines like:

```
subArray = new ArbitraryArray[5];
```

I'm aware this may not be the best way to go about creating an arbitrary dimensional array data structure, but I'd really like to figure out why this implementation is not working before potentially looking for better methods.

Also I am aware I shouldn't have a line like:

```
int array[5];
```

And that it should be a pointer instead so that there isn't a ton of wasted memory allocation for all the levels of the array above the bottom dimension. And I intend to modify it to that after I get this basic idea working.

Comment: Why not use one `std::vector` and index into it with a `at(x, y)` function that computes it with `y * row_length + x`? It's a bit easier...

Comment: Well the general principle you're referring to works and is something I've considered using. Though the way you put it is only good for a 2d array. You need to do repeated divisions and mods to get the arbitrary dimensionality. But yes I had considered using a one dimensional array of length dimension_1*dimension_2*...*dimension_n. And might even try that. For now I'm just trying to get this implementation to work.

Comment: Do you need an item for every cell of the maze? You might prefer a sparse array, which in C++ means an std::map or std::unordered_map where each key is a complete set of co-ordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't compiled anything, just visual inspection. What about this:

```
template<int array_length>
class ArbitraryArray{
public:
    int array[array_length];
    ArbitraryArray ** subArray;

    ArbitraryArray(){}

    ArbitraryArray(int depth){
        if (depth == 1)
            subArray = 0;
        else {
            subArray = new ArbitraryArray*[array_length];
            for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
                subArray[i] = new ArbitraryArray(depth - 1);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just a slight typo. It should be subArray = new ArbitraryArray*[array_length];

Comment: @DavidBandel: Thanks, fixed. Does this answer your question? If so, please show some love and hit +1 and accept the answer. That's the way we roll on StackOverflow (welcome!)

Comment: Would have loved to but it requires 15 reputation and for some reason, this question, which I thought I put enough time into making presentable for this site, was downvoted to 0. Oh well. You can't please anyone on the internet

Comment: You're back at 1 on this question now :)

Comment: And now 9 years later, I came back and accepted the answer

Answer (score 5):

How about using **std::vector** for allocating the correct amount of blank memory, which would be

```
sizeof(T) * dim1 * dim2 * dim3 * ...
```

Then write a helper class which takes care of the indexing, i.e., it will compute **i** from given **(x,y,z,...)**, whatever many dimensions you might have.

The beauty of this approach, IMHO, lies in not having to fiddle with pointers, and the helper class simply implements an indexing scheme of your preference ([row major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) or [column major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order)).

#### EDIT

When using **std::valarray**, things may become easier, as you can use **std::slice** and/or **std::gslice** to calculate your indexing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for once, if `depth` is greater than 2, you create five ArbitraryArrays, but you save all their pointers in one SubArray pointer. SubArray needs to be an array of pointers to ArbitraryArrays, try `ArbitraryArray *subArray[5];` and `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) subArray[i] = new ArbitraryArray(depth - 1)` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are creating an array that is all over the place in memory instead of one array that is stored in a continuous block of  memory. This could cause some issues depending on you handle the memory. e.g. using memcpy on it will never work.

I think a little more flexible approach would be create one large array and instead have an index into the array based on the number of dimensions

```
int n = static_cast<int>(pow( 5.0, static_cast<double>(depth) ));   
Type* a = new Type[ n ];
```

i.e. since you base your array size on 5, a 2-dim size would be 5x5 and a 3-dim 5x5x5

to access an element in the array say a[2,2,3] (0-based)  it could be calculated as

```
a[2*5*5 + 2*5 + 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Boost `multi_array` class. It is very flexible, efficient and can perform bounds checking.

- [Boost Multi-Array](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_array)